# Any advice on how to learn DITA for technical writing?

Tags: technical-writing, education, dita

My situation is such that I will be looking for a new job next week as this contract ends. For a tech writer, it is good to have DITA on the ole' resume. So, I just wanted to know if anyone has a site or book or tutorial on how to learn Darwin Information Typing Architecture (DITA).
Thanks all.

Comment: I *think* this question is about programming, not writing. What do our tech writers think? Leave this open or close it?

Comment: @NeilFein DITA is an information architecture/organizational scheme; while it's definitely on the geeky side and was presumably influenced by software principles, it's a tech-writing thing and IMO on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how much benefit you'll get on a resume from having read about, as opposed to *used*, DITA, but some knowledge is better than none.

DITA is both a specific framework and an approach.  My documentation group is currently working through the book *[DITA Best Practices: A Roadmap for Writing, Editing, and Architecting in DITA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132480522)* by Laura Bellamy, Michelle Carey, and Jenifer Schlotfeldt and we're finding it a good introduction so far.  We are not planning to migrate to the DITA *framework*, but we've been trying to apply a similar *approach* on our own and we're finding the book helpful for pointing out issues we haven't necessarily thought enough about.  The book contains a lot of information specific to the framework too, so it should be even more helpful for somebody who's going all-in on DITA.

The book is under 300 pages and not terribly dense, so you should be able to absorb it in less than a week.

Comment: Thank you so much Monica. I will definately look into the book DITA Best Practices: A Roadmap for Writing, Editing, and Architecting in DITA by Laura Bellamy, Michelle Carey, and Jenifer Schlotfeldt. DITA is much more involved and complicated that I realized.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this will be way too late but still, here's a free tool I found for learning DITA:

http://www.learningdita.com/

I'm currently following the course, although it's dropped down my todos a bit. I'm already familiar with most of the content from my own reading and from that perspective I'll say it's very comprehensive and thorough.

Although I already have the basic ideas I would recommend this for beginners, it definitely starts simple.

Here's the complete styleguide which explains in detail how to use each element if you're diving in and trying it out:

https://www.oxygenxml.com/dita/styleguide/webhelp-feedback/index.html

Answer (score 3):

For a more hands-on introduction, you might consider [downloading](https://www.dita-ot.org/download) and [installing](https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/installing-client.html) the [DITA Open Toolkit](https://www.dita-ot.org/). After you have set up the toolkit, you can:

1. Take a look at the DITA XML source for a real publication, namely the DITA Open Toolkit user's guide. The source is located in the docsrc folder, but you can also access it on [GitHub](https://github.com/dita-ot/docs).
2. Use this source to build the final output, for example, HTML or a PDF. To do this, see [Rebuilding the DITA-OT documentation](https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/rebuilding-docs.html) (or Chapter 20 in the PDF version).
3. Open a .dita topic file. Try to find that topic in the document by searching for its title. Notice how the XML follows a specific [topic structure](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/errata02/os/complete/part3-all-inclusive/archSpec/base/topicstructure.html). In DITA, a topic is the [basic unit of authoring](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/errata02/os/complete/part3-all-inclusive/archSpec/base/topicdefined.html).
4. Open a .ditamap file and compare what you see to the table of contents in this publication. Notice how it uses [DITA map elements](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/errata02/os/complete/part3-all-inclusive/archSpec/base/ditamap-elements.html) to organise a series of topics.
5. Make a small change to the title of a topic (perhaps after making a backup copy) and rebuild the publication. Notice how your change is rolled into the new version of the document.
6. At this point, you'll realise that it could be quite a challenge to write a document in DITA without some additional tool support. This is where "DITA-aware" tools such as [Oxygen XML Author](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author.html) come in to provide editing support. Note that Oxygen comes bundled with the DITA Open Toolkit. There is a list of tools that use the DITA Open Toolkit on [dita-ot.org](https://www.dita-ot.org/). See also [this list of DITA-related software tools](http://www.ditawriter.com/dita-related-software-tools/).

[Section 2.2.1.2](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/errata02/os/complete/part3-all-inclusive/archSpec/base/topicbenefits.html#benefitsoftopics) of the [Darwin Information Typing Architecture (DITA) Oasis standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/errata02/os/complete/part3-all-inclusive/dita-v1.3-errata02-os-part3-all-inclusive-complete.html#topicsoverview) contains more on the benefits of topic-based authoring.

For more examples of DITA-based authoring, check out the list of [Open Source DITA Collections](https://wiki.oasis-open.org/dita-adoption/ditaSourceSets) on oasis-open.org.